Range of the function $g(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 3}$

It is clear from the graph above that the range of g(x) is any number >=0. What I don't understand is why. If we replace g(x) with -1, for example, we can find a value for x inside the domain of g(x).
$-1 = \sqrt{x^2 - 3}$
$1 = x^2 - 3$
$x^2 = 4$
$x = \pm 2$
Why is that incorrect?

Because when we do the square root operation, we mean the "principal" square root - only the positive bit is considered.

So $\sqrt{x^2-3}$ can only result in a positive number? That makes a lot of sense, thank you!

$\sqrt x$ returns only positive values or 0. It can never ever return a negative value. It's the "$±$" we put before it to get 2 values while solving.  Your domain is $(-∞,-\sqrt 3] \cup [\sqrt 3, ∞]$ I suppose. And your range is $ [0,∞)$

Welcome to MSE. I allowed myself to embed the image rather than leaving it as a link, in accordance with MSE's practices

The key misunderstanding lies in the properties of the square root function. Specifically, the equation $-1 = \sqrt{x^2 - 3}$ is not valid because the square root function, by definition, always returns a non-negative number. That is, $\sqrt{y} \geq 0$ for all $y \geq 0$.
When you square both sides of the equation to remove the square root, the equation becomes $1 = x^2 - 3$, which is a valid transformation. However, you must also consider that the original expression has the square root, and so the only solutions are those that when plugged back into the original equation, would result in a non-negative number on both sides of the equation.
Let's follow the steps to clarify:

Assume $g(x) = -1$, then we have $-1 = \sqrt{x^2 - 3}$.
Squaring both sides gives $1 = x^2 - 3$.
This leads to $x^2 = 4$, which gives $x = \pm 2$.

However, when you plug $x = \pm 2$ back into the original function $g(x)$, you get $g(2) = \sqrt{2^2 - 3} = \sqrt{1} = 1$ and not $-1$. Similarly, $g(-2) = \sqrt{(-2)^2 - 3} = 1$.
Thus, the range of the function $g(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 3}$ is indeed all non-negative numbers, since the square root can never produce a negative output, and you can find some $x$ such that $g(x)$ will take any value greater than or equal to 0. The function will never produce a negative $g(x)$, so the range is $[0, \infty)$.

**A SIMPLE RANT: BEFORE YOU HEAD ON TO DOWNVOTE MY POST. PLEASE REMEMBER 2 THINGS: 1. I HAVE NOT COPIED IT FROM ANY AI TOOL 2. THIS IS ALL NATURAL. ** NOW YOU CAN DOWNVOTE. THERE IS A HOARD OF "SELF-PROCLAIMED CUSTODIANS" OF THIS PLATFORM. THIS IS FOR THOSE.
